# Where is the parameter -Isrc defined in CodeBlocks?

Tags: c++, parameters, codeblocks

I've got an existing project written in C++ from my predecessor. He used CodeBlocks as an IDE.
I never used this IDE and hardly programmed any C++. He used the tinyxml library, so I added it to the project.

When I try to build it, the build log says something like this:

```
g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -DBOOST_THREAD_USE_LIB=1 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0501 
-Wall -IC:\somepath\boost_1_74_0 -Iinclude -Isrc -IZ:\tinyxml 
-c C:\project\AsyncSerial.cpp -o obj\Debug\AsyncSerial.o
```

**Question:**
Where is `-Isrc -IZ:\tinyxml`  defined? I don't have any Z:-drive and want to define my own path to the library.

I searched inside the settings and project setup, but didn't find anything like that.

**Edit:** same goes for:

```
g++.exe -LC:\somepath\boost_1_74_0\stage\lib -o bin\Debug\project.exe obj\Debug\AsyncSerial.o obj\Debug\main.o obj\Debug\tinyxml\tinystr.o obj\Debug\tinyxml\tinyxml.o obj\Debug\tinyxml\tinyxmlerror.o obj\Debug\tinyxml\tinyxmlparser.o  -lws2_32  C:\Programme\boost\boost_1_48_0\stage\lib\libboost_filesystem-mgw46-mt-s-1_48.a C:\Programme\boost\boost_1_48_0\stage\lib\libboost_system-mgw46-mt-s-1_48.a C:\Programme\boost\boost_1_48_0\stage\lib\libboost_date_time-mgw46-mt-sd-1_48.a C:\Programme\boost\boost_1_48_0\stage\lib\libboost_program_options-mgw46-mt-sd-1_48.a C:\Programme\boost\boost_1_48_0\stage\lib\libboost_thread-mgw46-mt-1_48.dll.a C:\Programme\boost\boost_1_48_0\stage\lib\libboost_regex-mgw46-1_48.dll.a
```

Where does `-lws2_32` value come from? I installed boost to the path specified in `-L`. My boost path was set in global variables and it's the only global variable that is shown.

**Edit2:**
for information: my path to boost is a relative path in the project folder, and definitely not in program files.
Added pictures of my settings:
[image: Linker settings]
[image: linker search directory]
[image: error messages]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the include search directory configuration in

- menue "Project"
- entry "Build options ..."
- tab "Search directories"
- subtab "Compiler"

Linker search path nearby in subtab "Linker".

Config of libs to link in tab (not subtab) "Linker settings".

My CodeBlocks is 16.01, but that should not be too different whatever you use.

Quote of OP comment (to make this answer complete):

> I found it, they where defined in the Debug/Release Linker settings.

Here "it" refers to the reason/location of the linker paths which did not match the config screenshots in the question.

Comment: thank you. I found the "Z:/tinyxml" there and changed it. This error is gone now. But still, it tries to find boost in my Programm Files despite I set the global variable to my path and removed it from the search directories. Do you know where the -lws2_32 path come from?

Comment: to explain: my linker search directory is now the path to boost_1_74_0\libs only. and in linker settings there is only the -lws2_32 ; not a path.

Comment: In my environment, the libraries used by the linker and mentioned like `-lmingw32` (lowercase L) matches the libs I listed in the "Linker settings" tab, i.e. the second to last line in my current answer.

Comment: The linker search path I mentioned right after the bullet list, subtab "Linker".

Comment: Sorry if I seem cynical by only referring to existing parts of my answer. I am aware that I probably just do not get what you are asking. Please continue to describe details of your problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "not a path" (in config)? I do also not see a path relating to `-lws2_32` in your quotes of linker output. Which path are you looking for?

Comment: I added some pictures of my settings. I just don't get where he is getting the path (Programme/boost/boost_1_48_0...) from...

Comment: Sorry, that also is a mystery to me. May I recommend to create a separate question focusing on that mystic part of this question? I admit I ask because I think the non-mystery parts are answered and in my opinion the conflict of config (after you found it, with or without my help) are a new aspect. Your representation of that in your updated question is however clear and detailed. As a new question it will probably attract the right kind of knowledgable users.

Comment: nevermind, I found it, they where defined in the Debug/Release Linker settings.

Comment: Thanks for acceptin my answer inspite of that. But I think, now that you have found the detail (which I could have thought of ....), you can make your own most helpful answer. (I.e. accept it afterwards....) Otherwise I would like to improve my answer by incorporating what you found out yourself. For the perfect answer you should add screenshots similar to those in the question, showing the difference between debug and realease config.